# How can I deploy a local server easily?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, deployment, localhost

I'm making an application for a research project with interesting requirements. The data we are using right now is private and **cannot** be online in any form. However, I have to make it so that it *could* be online since this is a proof of concept.
I am using a MySQL database, Node.js/Express back-end and React (and possibly D3.js) front-end. Right now all I have is a dev environment through Visual Studio Code where I manually run the server and the React app before viewing the app on localhost:3000.

Despite these restrictions I have people who are expected to use this system without much technical background. So I need a way to deploy my local app and database so that these users will be able to set it up and run it simply and easily, without using the internet to host anything (even intranet is not allowed). Any ideas?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I dont think this is possible. If you would not use react and node but just JavaScript it would have been a solution to use SQLite but you complete setup is barely needing a server and you cannot setup a server on a users computer. Maybe he has not even admin rights and is therefore not able to install it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to create yourself a bash script that starts all required components, e.g.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/workspaces/frontend/
npm run start 

cd ~/workspaces/backend/
npm run start:database
npm run start
```

You could go as far as checking if the folders exist and if not clone the required repositories and run `npm install` or `git pull` as well.

So you only have to teach your coworkers to open a terminal and run one command `./start.sh`

Answer (score 0):

- You could use docker and docker-compose.
- You could also add Makefile.